# How can I convert a VS C++ project to CMake file to run on CLion for Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio, clion

Recently, I got an old C++ Visual Studio Project. It can work on Windows Server by Visual Studio 2019, but my PC is MacBook Pro. Now, I want to rebuild this project on my macbook by CLion for mac. How can I convert this VS C++ project to CMake file to run on CLion for Mac? Or does anyone else know how to run a C++ VS project on MacOS?

Comment: This question is way too broad.  I don't know of any tools that will just convert projects between two different compilers like this _and_ switch architectures.  Your best bet would be to analyze the project for any unusual settings, then build a new project from scratch and begin adding your source files.  Then configure any other dependencies like libraries etc, set up your build targets and just keep working through build errors until you get them all fixed.

Comment: Most likely you would need to write your own `CMakeLists.txt` after having learned some CMake. With that said if you have anything Windows specific in your program this may be a difficult task.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly CMake is frustrating for me, a solution that is enough, is to make a bash file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

g++ main.cpp ./*.cpp -o Out

./Out
```

And run it when you need to compile.

This bash file when executed uses the g++ compiler to compile main.cpp and the other .cpp files that you may have into a binary executable called Out

That's why the last line is ./Out it runs the binary.

Comment: CMake is something you can write a simple project in after a 20 minutes of research however when your project becomes more complicated with external dependencies, libraries ... you will need to spend days learning the more advanced parts. If you don't spend these days learning your experience will not be good.